# MVC 2.0 Routing Issue - Url parameter not recognized

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my AccountController class I have the following:

```
public ActionResult Verification(string userGuid)
{

    Debug.WriteLine(userGuid);
...
```

In my global.asax I have:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AccountVerification", 
    "{controller}/{action}/{userGuid}", 
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Verification", userGuid = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When I go to http://localhost/Account/Verification/123 ... theres no debug output... its not recognizing the parameter - which is my problem. Not sure what I'm missing.

I do want this parameter to be optional... if its not set then I return a different view.

**Edit**:
When I place a `Debug.WriteLine("hello world");` in the Verification function, it does output it so the routing appears to go to the correct function.

**Edit Again**:
The default controller is still present but I wouldn't think it would hit that route since it uses a different controller / action

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The route you have given us should match this - what other routes have you defined above it? It may be being picked up by a different route.

Comment: Not sure how it would be picked up by another route. Theres no other actions defined in my AccountController with the name Verification. I can confirm that it is hitting my Verification function, just outputs an empty string for userGuid.

Comment: Have you left the default route in, which is {controller}/{action}/{id}, and which would map your "123" to an "id" parameters? If so, because it is not defined as a parameter to your method, it will just pass "123" it in in the route data and leave userGuid blank.

Comment: Yes, the default one is in there as well.. but since its defined to use a different controller (Home) and action (Index) I would have thought it would not use this.

Comment: No, these are only the defaults that are specified - if it's above the one you have defined, it will pick up everything matching your pattern. Replace {controller} and {action} with the hard-coded values Account and Verification, and move your route above the default one. It will then pick up first, and everything else will trickle down to the default.

Answer (score 1):

The [RouteDegguer](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) will help identify which routes are being picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Put this definition at the top and see if it still doesn't work. first step to debugging routes

Comment: No i didn't. I mean't put your routing definition above any others you have (if you have any). This has helped me debug a problem a few times